# Search item on json object PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I have this kind of json objects and im trying to search an item under sales->products->id but i can't make it work. I hope someone could help me. Thanks!

```
"sales": [
        {
            "ID": 123456,
            "transaction_id": "123456789",
            "key": "sdawa57sd547sad4sadx54ad",
            "subtotal": 20,
            "tax": "0",
            "fees": null,
            "total": "20",
            "gateway": "paypal",
            "email": "email@email.com",
            "date": "2018-08-01 13:13:55",
            "discounts": null,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 1234,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "name": "Product 1",
                    "price": 20,
                    "price_name": ""
                }
            ]
        }
```

This is the code i used:

```
$content =     file_get_contents($url);

$results= json_decode($content, TRUE);

foreach($results->sales as $item)
{
    if($item->products->id == "1234")
    {
        echo $item->products->name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've passed the second parameter as `true` to [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), your `$results` variable is an array, so you need to access it like that:

```
foreach($results['sales'] as $item) {
    foreach ($item['products'] as $product) {
        if ($product['id'] == '1234') echo $product['name'];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Product 1
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/sbP8L)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find which sales have the product, then you should do this

```
$results= json_decode($content);

$productid = "1234"; //product you want to search for
foreach($result->sales as $sale)
{
  $keys = array_keys(array_column($sale->products, 'id'), $product_id);
  if(!empty($keys))
      $saleIDs[] = $sale->ID;
}
var_dump($saleIDs); //contains all the sale IDs that have the product
```

Read about [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).